# andengine applyLinearImpulse don't work

Tags: android, andengine, physics

I have a Dynamic body. On tap to screen I try to jump body by apply `LinearImpulse` for body, but after execution its didn't get effect. Just nothing changes
this my tap to screen method:

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
     if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){  
Debug.d("jump test");   
                int index = mPlayer.getCurrentTileIndex()-1;        
                mPlayer.setCurrentTileIndex(Math.abs(index));
                //mPlayerBody.applyForce(new Vector2(10, -10), mPlayerBody.getWorldCenter());
                mPlayerBody.applyLinearImpulse(99990, -999999, mPlayerBody.getPosition().x, 
                                mPlayerBody.getPosition().y);


    //mPlayerBody.applyLinearImpulse(10, 10, mPlayerBody.getPosition().x, mPlayerBody.getPosition().y);
    }
    return false;
}
```

and this how I create physics for body:

```
final FixtureDef PLAYER_FIX = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0,
            0, 1, false);
    mPlayerBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, mPlayer,
            BodyType.DynamicBody, PLAYER_FIX);
    mScene.attachChild(mPlayer);
    physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(mPlayer,
            mPlayerBody, true, false));
```

and on create scene i use:

`physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2( 0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);`

Whats wrong?  Why linear impulse didn't apply? also I try to use apply `LinearVelocity` but this also has no effect.

please note: sorry for my English

Comment: Is body moving freely already? You deffo did registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld)?

Comment: yes, in onCreateScene i set mScene.registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);
body is moving. body begins falling immediately after attach to mScene.

Comment: i guess that Debug.d("jump test");  is executed correctly. Try to modify mass of the body (forst argument which is 0 in your case). Also jumping should be handled but linearVelocity, not linearImpulse. Try this: setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(playerBody.getLinearVelocity().y, -40));

Comment: Mateusz Gaweł , yes, thank you. it's work!

Answer (score 0):

PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(flaot density , float elasticity ,float friction)
the mass of the the body is 0 if density = 0.